# Rescale column in dataframe?

Tags: r, plyr, rescale

I have a dataframe called `data` where I would like to rescale the values in the 4th field to a range of 0-1000 and round the scaled value to the nearest integer. I'm trying to use `ddply`, `round` and `rescale`:

```
scaled_data <- ddply(data, round(rescale(data[,4], to=c(0,1000), from=range(data[,4], na.rm=TRUE)), 0)
```

The above code throws this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(envir, exprs) : undefined columns selected
```

Can anyone point out the problem or a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making it too complicated -- I don't see why you need `ddply` at all.

```
dd[,4] <- round(ggplot2::rescale(dd[,4],to=c(0,1000))
```

(I'm using `ggplot2::rescale` because you did, but `(x-min(x))/diff(range(x))*1000` would do the same thing)

Or if you know the *name* of the fourth column you can:

```
dd <- transform(dd,fourth=rescale(fourth,to=c(0,1000)))
```